# slf4j: failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.staticloggerbinder". with logback-classic

Tags: slf4j, logback-classic

My pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>       
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

But, error occured. -> "slf4j: failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.staticloggerbinder". slf4j: defaulting to no-operation (nop) logger implementation"

I excluded commons-logging, log4j1 library.

What should I do?

I want to show logback log.